# Using Sitecore Rocks for Solr Search Enabled Sitecore instance

Tags: solr, sitecore-rocks

I have noticed this strange error in my instance after attempting to connect sitecore rocks with my local sitecore instance 
which I have recently migrated to solr from Lucene search provider.

**Actual Issue:**

I have been playing around with sitecore rocks for long time & it was with Lucene enabled instances.
All (including mine) instances were migrated to SOLR provider & when I tried to connect Sitecore rocks with my local instance, 
I have received ‘Connection failed’ even after deploying Sitecore rocks component dlls & service files.
Now when I try to access sitecore login page or any page, I have received this error.

[image]

**Some Analysis:**

There was no much information and also specially no errors in the sitecore logs & I have started disabling all config files step by step but which went in vain.
When I had a close look at the log entry, I see log entry stopped logging soon after ‘Sitecore.Rocks.Server.dll’ & it should have recorded ‘Sitecore.Rocks.Lucene*.dlls’  log entries 
Which were missing.

[image]

**Temporary solution:**
As soon as i delete ‘Sitecore.Rocks*.dlls including ‘Sitecore.Rocks.Lucene*.dlls’ I’m able to get the sitecore login page. :)

**Queries:**
Do we have Sitecore rocks for solr enabled sitecore instance ? or should I perform any alternate steps to connect my local instance(SOLR enabled) ?
If no, are we restricted to connect Sitecore rocks only if your instance is with lucene search ? :(

Comment: what version of rocks are you using?

Comment: It's 2.x version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please look on changelog of **Sitecore Rocks Github** Repository. Looks like you don't need on this version ‘**Sitecore.Rocks.Lucene*.dlls**. Please make a new install of the module and see if you still have the error. If you still have please delete 
**Sitecore.Rocks.Lucene*.dlls** and other dll that are not needed anymore.

https://github.com/JakobChristensen/Sitecore.Rocks/blob/03c1f02eb1487feab431614ef1bde1bf65440bd9/CHANGELOG.md

[image]

Comment: it could be a big workaround if we stick with older version of sitecore rocks + solr enabled sitecore instances. ?